# Ionic 2 + Meteor How to set DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL

Tags: javascript, meteor, ionic-framework, ddp

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/server) to create a ionic2 + meteor app. I've put the meteor backend on heroku and am trying to connect the ionic app to it.

How/where can I set **meteor_runtime_config**.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem, tried in index.html to no avail. I found a workaround by modifying

```
DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL:"http://localhost:3000"
```

with

```
DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL:"http://yourserver.com:XXXX"
```

in meteor-client-side.bundle.js and meteor-client-side.bundle.min.js (that are located on your node_modules)

However this only a TEMPORARY solution. Im also looking for the proper way.